# cakephp pre-fill form on method get

Tags: cakephp

I have a search form and I'm submitting it using GET method. After form submission, I need to pre-fill the form with submitted values. If it is POST, cake will automatically taking care of this but it is not working for GET. I have created form and form controls using cakephp's form helper. Is there any simple way to pre-fill the fields instead of setting each field manually ?
Im using cakephp2.x

Comment: This also applies to CakePHP 3, so does this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14846210/122511

Answer (score 6):

I know this question was asked a while ago but I recently had the same problem.

When you use GET, `CakeRequest` will not fill the `CakeRequest::data` property.
The Form Helper usually uses this property to fill the values of an input. So you must firstly fill this property with your GET data somewhere in your controller. Eg:

```
$this->request->data = $this->request->query;
```

Your next problem is that the Form Helper ignores the model you set for your form if you use GET. Unfortunately this behavior is not documented but it does mention [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html):

> You can also pass `false` for `$model`. This will place your form data into the array: `$this->request->data` (instead of in the sub-array: `$this->request->data['Model']`). This can be handy for short forms that may not represent anything in your database.

So you will need to set the model to `false` when you create your search form. eg:

```
echo $this->Form->create(false, array('type' => 'get'));
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, worked a treat. Can cake tidy up the url so that it doesn't show empty params, i.e &document_id=51cd5d1a-4e4c-4645-89eb-28c1d4e3f9c1&industry_id=&tags=&success=&rating=

Comment: Not really. That would be best achieved with jQuery or other JavaScript when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 3 you can simply create your form like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create($user);
```

and than in controller action just set $user as Entity

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by populating the `$this->request->data` property in your controller.

For example, let's say you have this as your form:

```
 <?= $this->Form->create('Search'); ?>
 <?= $this->Form->input('query'); ?>
 <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Then in your controller action use:

```
 $this->request->data('Search.query', 'search data');
```

Comment: The request type shouldn't matter at this stage. That should give the input `data[Search][query]` a value of 'search data'.

Comment: If it is post, then only data[Search][query] is working. Otherwise the field name is displaying as just query, its not even considering what name we are giving for form. If it post, field name will be displayed data[Search][query]